# Facebook Share issue, how to share a particular image

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am working on one project, in that i am using facebook sharing. Its working properly but i need to share a particular image only.

If you want to check the demo then please go through below url

http://localnbook.aseuminfotech.in/

In that, in header you will find the Facebook icon, i am using that icon to share the things.

When sharing i want to show the Logo, instead of banner image, so please help me for the same. 
For sharing below url is going to be generated

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=618251314925642&client_id=618251314925642&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalnbook.aseuminfotech.in%2F&display=page&link=http%3A%2F%2Flocalnbook.aseuminfotech.in%2F&caption=See%20Everything,%20Book%20Everything&from_login=1

Let me know, if you any confusions.

Thanks,
Nik

Answer (score 1):

Specify a og:image. As you can see at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Flocalnbook.aseuminfotech.in%2F it complains that you haven't set it